# Uncaught ReferenceError with type.js on a basic webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I'm running the code below on chrome http://localhost:8000/ and getting the following error in the console:

`.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined at particles.js:1`

All my files are in the same folder.

My index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script 
scr="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"> . 
</script>

<script src="particles.js" defer='defer'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My style.css

```
#particles-js{
background-color: red;
height: 100vh;
}
```

My particles.js file

```
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

My particles.json

```
{
"particles": {
"number": {
"value": 80,
}
}
```

Before this I first tried to get this work on a Ruby on rails app but got similar errors. I'm still new to javascript so it's probably something simple.

Here it is in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nj3attvb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first correct your script `src` attribute:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

Then try to wrap your particles.js file to:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // all your particles.js code here
}
```

Comment: That seemed to work but now im getting a completly new error : ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 58 ```

Comment: @Connor This error means  that your json which you tried to parse is invalid, can you represent it?

Comment: I just check and it works on safari... lol the only time safari has been better than chrome.

Comment: @Connor try to parse this json insted yours:

{
 "particles": {
  "number": {
   "value": 80
  }
 }
}